# Using Bash to Count Lines of Code That I Have Written

Tags: linux, bash, lines-of-code

I know that this script: `find . -name '*' | xargs wc -l` will count all the lines of code recursively in a directory, however since I am using plugins, the script will count those too.

I just want to be able to count the lines of code that I have written. If I add a commented string to each file that I write, how will I modify that script so it only counts files containing that specific string (perhaps something like `originalCode-01-NoPlugin-`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are __we__ supposed to know how many lines of code have __you__ written?

Comment: @devnull files that I write will contain the commented string `originalCode-01-NoPlugin-` is that what you mean?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `grep -rl 'originalCode-01-NoPlugin-' . | wc -l`

Comment: @devnull that just brings back the number of occurrences of the phrase, not the lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -rl 'originalCode-01-NoPlugin-' ./ | xargs wc -l` does the trick, thanks for pointing me in the right direction @devnull

It first finds the files and then counts the lines of code.